# How to put special characters on ssid

Tags: wireless

[image]

Refer to the picture above. I would like to add the word "FREE" for my SSID. How do I do that? I've seen this ssid around my area but I don't know how to implement it on my router.

Comment: What model is the device?

Comment: Recall that an SSID is up to 32 bytes of... whatever, which may or may not be specified to be UTF8 as of the latest revision of the standard. So you're quite dependant on what the developers of your router software and the various clients have done to try and display SSID names. To be honest, using Emoji in an SSID sounds like a good way to trigger buggy behaviour in some clients, and not something I would do on a production network.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm using mikrotik router

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like an Emoji, hex code 1F193:

If the interface of your router allows it, you can simply copy and paste the above character on the SSID text field.

Note: the style of the character will appear different depending on the client device displaying the list of Wi-Fi networks. See [this complete Emoji list](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).

Comment: I'm not able to add this to my mikrotik router. Using routerboard winbox software. Do you have any experience on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to be cute with a new SSID and put an ‘ in it only to find that many of my devices wouldn’t accept it. I ended up using a guest network without the ‘ to get things working. It’s not about the router, it’s about the devices inability to accept the special characters. It’s a cold rainy Sunday and I’m going to completely redo the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

i found this website [1] which encodes the given name/emoji and shows a console command:

```
"example ":
/interface wireless set X ssid="\65\78\61\6D\70\6C\65\20\F0\9F\92\BB"
```

[1]https://r-1.ch/mikrotik-unicode-ssid-generator.php